# Plotting the intersections between two functions

Tags: plotting, education

I am trying to use the code below to plot intersections on the graph between the two functions, but I receive an error regarding stating it must be a pure function or list of pure functions. I am using the code directly from the manual, I am just not sure what I am missing. Also plotting the values with the points would be excellent.

```
{j, k} = {{x^3 - 4 x}, {2 x + 6}}
Plot[{j, k}, {x, -10, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {(f - g)/.x->#&}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

Comment: 1) `f` and `g` are not defined, replace these with `j`, and `k`. 2) Remove the inner brakets from your definitions of `j` and `k` so that `{j,k} = {x^3-4*x, 2*x+6}`. Should work fine.

Comment: Seems you're copying examples from the docs.;If you modify one thing at a time you'll _at the very least_ be sure where your problem is

Answer (score 4):

First, you will often find it easier to deal with *Mathematica* when you define and work with functions, not expressions. That is certainly the case here.

```
j[x_] := x^3 - 4 x
k[x_] := 2 x + 6
```

Second, when following examples form the Documentation Center, be careful to pay attention to the smallest details. It is a good idea to also read what is discussed under Details in the documentation article. Since `j` and `k` have been defined as functions, it is much easier to adapt the example.

```
Plot[{j[x], k[x]}, {x, -10, 10},
  MeshFunctions -> {j[#] - k[#] &},
  Mesh -> {{0}},
  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image: plot]